# Concatenate JSON files

Tags: json, list, merge, jq

I would like to concatenate all the json files in a specific folder.

I installed jq tools and tried different things but no success so far.

Thanks for your help!

Example :
1.json

```
[{
     "id": "1",
     "name": "Product 1"
},{
     "id": "2",
     "name": "Product 2"
},{
     "id": "3",
     "name": "Product 3"
}]
```

2.json

```
[{
     "id": "10",
     "name": "Product 10"
},{
     "id": "11",
     "name": "Product 11"
},{
     "id": "12",
     "name": "Product 12"
}]
```

output.json

```
[{
     "id": "1",
     "name": "Product 1"
},{
     "id": "2",
     "name": "Product 2"
},{
     "id": "3",
     "name": "Product 3"
},{
     "id": "10",
     "name": "Product 10"
},{
     "id": "11",
     "name": "Product 11"
},{
     "id": "12",
     "name": "Product 12"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Read in both files through using `inputs` (which works best if you also add the `--null-input` (or `-n`) option):

```
jq -n '[inputs[]] ' 1.json 2.json
```

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Product 1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Product 2"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Product 3"
  },
  {
    "id": "10",
    "name": "Product 10"
  },
  {
    "id": "11",
    "name": "Product 11"
  },
  {
    "id": "12",
    "name": "Product 12"
  }
]
```

Comment: Wow ! Thanks !

Here's the command with my specific needs : jq -n '[inputs] | add' *.json > file.json

Do you have an idea if I can sort by id ?

Comment: @Zjeed Sure. Redirect by adding `> outfile.json` as you also would with other commands (just don't try to overwrite one of the input files - use temporary files for that). To input certain files from certain directories, name them directly when listing the input files. -- `jq -n '[inputs[]]' from/here/*.json and/there/*.json > output.json`

Comment: @Zjeed Sure, sorting is also possible. To sort by a string key use `[inputs[]] | sort_by(.id)`. Your `id` field is a string but it looks like you want to rather sort by a numeric key. Then convert it accordingly (just for soorting, in the output it will stay a string) `[inputs[]] | sort_by(.id | tonumber)`